# Proof regarding a sequence of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to prove the following: if $(F_{n})$ is a sequence of closed subsets of a complete metric space $S$, and if the union $F=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}$ contains a nonempty open set, then so does at least one of the sets $F_{n}$. My attempt is as follows:

Suppose $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}$ contains a nonempty open set. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}$ has nonempty interior. So $S$ \ $ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}\triangleq \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}($S \ $F_{n}$) has empty interior, and so is not dense. Therefore, $(S$ \ $F_{n})$ is not a sequence of dense open subsets of $S$. Therefore at least one element of that sequence, say $S$\ $F_{m}$, is not dense. Thus its complement $F_{m}$ is dense.

Beyond this point I am stuck. Thank you.

Comment: How do you deduce from the fact that $S\setminus F_m$ is not dense that $F_m$ is dense?